# Passing Variable from WordPress PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using two WordPress plugins - Snippets for inserting PHP code and Scripts n Styles for inserting JavaScript.

My goal is to take a logged-in user's email address and pre-populate a form.

The PHP code in Snippets is:

```
<?php
function get_user() {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;
}
add_action( 'init', 'get_user', 10 );
?>
```

The code in Scripts n Styles is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

var useremail = "<?php echo json_encode($user_email); ?>";

document.getElementsByName("ElementName")[0].value = useremail;
}
</script>
```

But instead of getting user@domain.com I get the quoted text inserted into the form:

> `<?php echo json_encode($user_email); ?>`

Any idea of what is going wrong or a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Is the code in script and styles rendered with php or is it just a javascript file?

Comment: JavaScript is embedded into the head element

Comment: It should work like expected, see https://3v4l.org/ffDZf

Comment: The JS is embedded into the head, but the php code in the JavaScript will not be parsed. Scripts n Styles does not run PHP on the JavaScript string, just prints it out as is.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a useful function to localize scripts to be passed from PHP to be used in JavaScript. This can be done by using the `wp_localize_script()` function before enqueueing the script.

Here is an example of this in use from the WordPress Codex. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Registering and enqueueing the script:

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

Using that data in JavaScript:

```
// alerts 'Some string to translate'
alert( object_name.some_string);
```

Here is a good writeup on how this works: http://www.webtipblog.com/localize-scripts-in-wordpress-to-use-php-variables-in-javascript/